# Popen.communicate() not working properly

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, shell, popen

I am pretty new to Python. I am using `Python 2.7` 
I am trying to automate a command in shell using `python`. I run the command using Popen and I am passing an argument to the subprocess using `Popen.communicate()`.
The command I am trying to execute is basically a Java application and, when it executes, it finds multiple main classes. I need to enter the index of main class to be executed, for which I use `Popen.communicate()`. In the output screen, it shows that the number was entered, but it throws `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

Why is it taking the input string as a null string?

Here is the code I use:

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
cmd = ["sudo", "./sbt", "project java-examples", "run"]
proc = Popen(cmd, shell=False,stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
print proc.communicate('1')[0]
proc.stdin.close()
```

And this is the output I get

> [info] Loading project definition from
>   /home/hduser/morey/kafka/project [info] Set current project to Kafka
>   (in build file:/home/hduser/morey/kafka/) [info] Set current project
>   to kafka-java-examples (in build file:/home/hduser/morey/kafka/)
>
> Multiple main classes detected, select one to run:
>
> [1]  TestProducer
>     [2]  kafka.examples.SimpleConsumerDemo
>     [3]  kafka.examples.KafkaConsumerProducerDemo
>
> Enter number: 1
>   Invalid number: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
>   input string: "" java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
>           at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last java-examples/compile:run for the full
>   output. [error] (java-examples/compile:run) No main class detected.
>   [error] Total time: 2 s, completed Feb 3, 2016 5:46:31 AM

Comment: Try to send a number instead of strin, it may help 
print proc.communicate(1)[0]

Comment: @AlokThakur I have tried that but Popen.communicate() can take only a string argument.

Comment: Have you considered trying sending a newline as part of your input? `'1\n'` perhaps.

Comment: @Amber Thank You !!!! That did the job. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a newline character to your input:

```
print proc.communicate('1\n')[0]
```